# MySQL: Insert values to json object

Tags: mysql, json

I have a DB that gets data from sensors. I store the data in 4 jsons: `in1`, `in2`, `out1`, `out2`.

**Example of data:**

```
[50, 100, 203, 49, 29, ... ]
```

The length of every json is 128.

I'm trying to write a function that will do the following: **get 4 jsons (in the above format) then create and return a new json object of the same format**, but I'm kinda stuck on the syntax.

```
BEGIN
 declare idx int(11);
 declare new_arr JSON;
 set idx = 0;
 set new_arr = 0;

 while (idx < 128) Do
  JSON_INSERT(new_arr, idx ,get_element(in1_arr, idx) - get_element(out1_arr, idx) + 
  get_element(in2_arr, idx) - get_element(out2_arr, idx));
 return new_arr
END
```

`get_element` is a function I wrote that gets a json like the one above, and an index, and returns the value for that index.

The result should be, eventually, a json object - every element of the new json object will store the result of in1[i] - out1[i] + in2[i] - out2[i].

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: I edited the question now.